# Start a new line in flex object

Tags: css, material-ui

```
<Popper id={"simplePopper"} open={this.context.loading}  
style={{display: "flex",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
backgroundColor: 'red',opacity:'0.5',width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>

<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
Loading....

<Popper>
```

In this case , `fa-spin icon` and `loading...` is in the same line.

So I try some,

```
<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
<br/>
Loading....
```

or

```
<p>
<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
</p>
<p>
Loading....
</p>
```

or

```
<div>
<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
</div>
<div>
Loading....
</div>
```

Any way doesn't make new line.

How can I separate `icon` and `Loading...`??

---

I solved with this code.

Thank you for your help

```
<div>
<div style={{flexWrap: "wrap", width:"100%"}}>
<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
</div>
<div>
<Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
Loading..
{this.context.progress}
</Typography>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share running code link of it. however, looking at your query I guess,
on your ```spin``` add them into a new div and add class```flex-grow:1``` Hope that would work

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved.and I updated the article with right code.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement and really appreciate, that you have taken up the time, to update your question with the solution as well. Your solution is also correct, and its just the other way around, I guess even ```flex-grow:1``` would have also work. Since its doing the same thing as ```width: 100%```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to the parent `flex-wrap: wrap;` and first child must be width 100%.

Or you can set `flex-direction: column` if you have only 2 child elements.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. the problem is solved.and I updated the article with right code.